# Design a trait in Rust with a mutable getter and an immutable getter and that implements the immutable getter by default

Tags: rust, immutability, traits, mutable, unsafe

I want to design a trait with a mutable and an immutable getter to some field of `self`.
However, I want that the implementer of the trait has to implement only one method, typically the mutable getter.

I have found this solution ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ae07dd805c5e78a54a9f2818966c743a)):

```
pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T; 
    
    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T {
        let ptr = self as *const Self as *mut Self;
        &* unsafe { &mut *ptr }.inside_mut()
    }
}

pub struct Data(String);
impl MyTrait<String> for Data {
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String { &mut self.0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data(format!("Foo"));
    let x: &String = data.inside_ref();
    let y: &String = data.inside_ref();
    println!("x -> {x}");
    println!("y -> {y}");
    *data.inside_mut() = format!("Bar");
    println!("data.0 -> {}", data.0);
}
```

Result:

```
Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.93s
     Running `target/release/playground`

Standard Output

x -> Foo
y -> Foo
data.0 -> Bar
```

My question: is this approach sound?

Comment: Not an expert on unsafe rust, but no, this does not seem to be safe as miri detects UB. You can run miri on the playground. You can find the option in the tools menu in the top right corner.

Comment: Technical remark: You are probably asking whether this approach is [sound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html), not safe.

Comment: Exactly! I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not sound.

The user could modify `self` in his implementation of `inside_mut`, which would also modify the struct in `inside_ref`.

Like this:

```rust
pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T;

    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T {
        let ptr = self as *const Self as *mut Self;
        &*unsafe { (&mut *ptr).inside_mut() }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
}

impl MyTrait<i32> for MyStruct {
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {
        self.value += 1;
        &mut self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Important: this is not `mut`!!!
    let x = MyStruct { value: 42 };

    println!("{:?}", x);
    x.inside_ref();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

```
MyStruct { value: 42 }
MyStruct { value: 43 }
```

That means that this implementation is [unsound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> Behavior considered undefined
>
> - Mutating immutable data. All data inside a `const` item is immutable. Moreover, all data reached through a shared reference or data owned by an immutable binding is immutable, unless that data is contained within an `UnsafeCell<U>`.

Comment: Oh yes! I did not see this subtlety!

Comment: Even if the user does not do that it's immediate UB, as converting a shared reference to a mutable reference is immediate UB, even if it is not mutated.

Answer (score 0):

After a look at Finomnis' answer, I come to this solution ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=67c93e0f4c8cec67197d549cabd9efa7)) for which miri does not produce a UB alert:

```
use core::cell::UnsafeCell;
pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        let ptr = self.implement_ref().get();
        unsafe { &mut *ptr }
    }

    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T {
        let ptr = self.implement_ref().get();
        unsafe { & *ptr }
    }

    fn implement_ref(&self) -> &UnsafeCell<T>;
}

pub struct Data(UnsafeCell<String>);

impl Data {
    pub fn new(s:String) -> Self {
        Data(UnsafeCell::new(s))
    }    
}

impl MyTrait<String> for Data {
    fn implement_ref(&self) -> &UnsafeCell<String> { &self.0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data::new(format!("Foo"));
    let x: &String = data.inside_ref();
    let y: &String = data.inside_ref();
    println!("x -> {x}");
    println!("y -> {y}");
    *data.inside_mut() = format!("Bar");
    println!("data.0 -> {}", data.inside_ref());
}
```

---

However, I still have a question. miri produces a UB alert for the following code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=c325e540eadb6954ffdf171417fc6dd4)):

```
pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T;
    
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T  {
        let ptr = self.inside_ref() as *const T as *mut T;
        unsafe { &mut *ptr }
    }
}

pub struct Data(String);
impl MyTrait<String> for Data {
    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &String { &self.0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data(format!("Foo"));
    let x: &String = data.inside_ref();
    let y: &String = data.inside_ref();
    println!("x -> {x}");
    println!("y -> {y}");
    *data.inside_mut() = format!("Bar");
    println!("data.0 -> {}", data.0);
}
```

But the nice counterexample provided by Finomnis does not work for this case. Could someone provide an illustration of the unsoundness of the latter case?

---

EDIT: inspired from the counterexample of cafce25 ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=57c8836829f4084e59bc3b443546816c)):

```
static IMMUTABLE_STATIC_STR: &'static str = "IMMUTABLE FOO";

pub trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T;
    
    fn inside_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T  {
        let ptr = self.inside_ref() as *const T as *mut T;
        unsafe { &mut *ptr }
    }
}

pub struct Data;
impl MyTrait<&'static str> for Data {
    fn inside_ref(&self) -> &&'static str { &IMMUTABLE_STATIC_STR }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = Data;
    let x: &&'static str = data.inside_ref();
    let y: &&'static str = data.inside_ref();
    println!("x -> {x}");
    println!("y -> {y}");
    *data.inside_mut() = "Bar";
    println!("data.inside_ref() -> {}", data.inside_ref());
}
```

Result:

```
Standard Error

   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.61s
     Running `target/release/playground`

Standard Output

x -> IMMUTABLE FOO
y -> IMMUTABLE FOO
data.inside_ref() -> IMMUTABLE FOO
```

Comment: First, for new question please ask a new SO question. Second, `UnsafeCell` works but it's a bad idea. It's much better to just have two methods to implement.

Comment: Miri does not (and cannot) check soundness. It only checks if one execution of your program contains UB.

Comment: All right! I don't think a new question is worth it. And thank you for your advice!

Comment: I agree with you that the unsafe approach should be avoided. But, there are certainly cases where the trait designer wants to be sure that both methods refer to the same data. That said, the problem can anyway be avoided by implementing only the mutable getter and dealing with the induced constraint.

Comment: `fn inside_ref(&self) -> &T { &IMMUTABLE_STATIC_T }` uh oh.

Comment: Great! I still have a lot to learn before I can produce counterexamples with such ease.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman **I don't understand why an example ticks you off so much, OP didn't understand why it's a bad idea, An example tells more than 1000 words of you that it's immediate UB**

Comment: @cafce25 It's a bad idea because it's UB, in all cases and examples.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes of course, I don't see how an example to help OP understand is a bad thing that has to be ranted about though.

Comment: @cafce25 It may drive the OP (and I think it drove them) to think that only when we find a counterexample it's bad.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I asked that question because I knew that this solution with mutable reference conversion was wrong and I wanted to know how to avoid UB. As far as I am concerned, I don't need a counterexample to be convinced not to use UB. However, I will have to introduce rust to some C/C++ programmers, and counterexamples will be useful for me in this context. I already have counterexamples of UB implied by compiler optimisation. But the examples in this post are different, because they are the consequence of the language. For me, it's really interesting to see that.